# std::vector::emplace vs placement new

Tags: c++, c++11

When I want to construct an object within a vector I can write the following code:

```
class NonTrivialType {
    NonTrivialType() = default;
    NonTrivialType(InitParam param){/* implementation */};
};

// array with 100 default-constructed objects in it
std::vector<NonTrivialType> data(100);

int main(){
    // prepare some init parameters
    InitParam param{/* some data */};
    // construct an object at 50th position
    data.emplace(data.begin()+49, param);
}
```

Which works fine, but seems to generate more code than if I'd use a placement new instead like so:

```
int main(){
    // prepare some init parameters
    InitParam param{/* some data */};
    // construct an object at 50th position
    new (&data[49]) NonTrivialType{param};
}
```

My question is, why would I use `emplace` instead of placement `new`?

Comment: I would expect inserting an element to produce more code than overwriting one.

Comment: Vector has to allocate on `emplace` to make room for the new element, and also it has to move every elements past `49` one position further in the array.

Comment: why would you use placement `new` instead of `emplace` ? They are doing something different

Comment: Thanks. pls see my comment on accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your programs are not equivalent.

`data.emplace(data.begin()+49, param);` inserts a new element into the vector. That increases the vector size and shifts elements past the insertion point.

`new (&data[49]) NonTrivialType{param};` overwrites an existing element. Without destroying an existing one first and thus causing undefined behaviour if `NonTrivialType` has a non-trivial destructor.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Quantify the probability please.

Comment: No, it's *actually* not undefined behavior if the destructor is trivial. Edit : But it's best to call the destructor anyway. Anyone could change `NonTrivialType` later in such a way that a destructor call would now be required and there would be no way of spotting this new error. I'd still consider not calling the destructor explicitly an error in any case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Okay.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I wrongfully thought that emplace constructs an object by overwriting an existing element. Should have read the documentation more carefully.