# Std::vector vs. placement new for communicating const array with size known at run-time

Tags: c++, stdvector, placement-new

I have two methods for creating a list of objects at run-time which have potential downsides that I'd like to consider. Ultimately I am wondering which one more e

The criteria of my problem:

- One major object will contain a fixed collection of minor objects (technically representing a 2d array)
- Desire not to implement default constructor for the minor object since it will have some const paramter that gets assigned via user input (default may lead to invalid states elsewhere in the program!)
- Very few (1 for most cases) of the major object will be needed per program execution
- The state of each minor object will likely depend on some user input (likely in form of a config file).

My understanding:

- Std::vector is likely more clear in how objects are created but I don't want to encourage changing the size of the array which I believe is a somewhat implied feature of any std::vector.
- Placement new seems to successfully create pool of objects as desired while discouraging increasing or decreasing the size of the array since there is no default function for this.
- I don't see any difference in downstream usage so leaning towards placement new despite the less frequent syntax since it discourages downstream resizing.

Does this reasoning align with the intention of placement new or am I missing a more appropriate standard container?

In the example below object list option 1 & 2 represent a std::vector based approach vs. placement new respectively.
For simplicity I left out any exception handling.
The ideal downstream usage (e.g. no resize) looks the same to me (access via [] operator).

For reference [std::vector::emplace vs placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046408/stdvectoremplace-vs-placement-new) might seem like a relevant question but I am trying to find an ideal solution for this particular set of criteria where the other question is considerably more vague. It is also possible that a different container or pattern would better solve this and that the two options here are simply a starting point.

```
#include <vector>

class minorObj{
    const int value;
    public:
    minorObj() = delete;
    minorObj(int x):value(x){}
};



class majorObj{
    const int N;
    public:
    std::vector<minorObj> objList_op1;
    minorObj*            objList_op2;
    majorObj(int size):N(size){
        objList_op1.reserve(N);
        objList_op2 = static_cast<minorObj*>(operator new[](N * sizeof(minorObj)));
        for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
            objList_op1.emplace_back(minorObj(i));
            new(&objList_op2[i]) minorObj(i);
        }
    }
    ~majorObj(){
        for(int i = N -1; i >= 0; i--){
            objList_op2[i].~minorObj();
        }
    }
};

void someFn(){majorObj(25);} //added some different scope to emphasize need for proper memory mgmt

int main(){
    someFn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about wrapping an `std::vector` into a class that only exposes functions that cannot change its size? Side note: this `majorObj` will fall in flames as soon as it is copied.

Comment: Why is `objList_op1` public in the example? Wouldn't making it private solve your issue with changing its size?

Comment: If you want a *fixed size* array, then just use `std::array`.

Comment: *"Desire not to implement default constructor for the minor object since it will have some const paramter that gets assigned via user input"* This is usually not a desirable approach, as it leads to complications like the one being asked here. Class invariants can be maintained with encapsulation and setters/getters instead.

Comment: Side note: in my 25+ years as a professional developer, I've never encountered a situation where placement new was the right solution to a problem - I'd be very sceptical of that route.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I would disagree. Modeling an empty/invalid state for objects which shouldn't logically have one adds complexity to the invariants.

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP is clearly passing the size at runtime to the constructor.

Comment: @Quentin An object doesn't need to be nullable to benefit from value semantics. If you choose that a default constructed instance is equivalent to a moved-from instance, it makes sense for most types to be default constructible. This question is a good example, just like after move you have a husk object, sometimes you need a place to put a value before the value is ready to be provided. Sometimes an object isn't representing any particular value, whether what it represents has a logical void state or not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl doesn't size need to be known at compile time for std::array? Otherwise I would've went with that.

Comment: @Nelfeal In the actual code it is private but that's beside the point since I don't want the majorObj to change the size of it's own array.

Comment: @20lbpizza Aren't you the one writing `majorObj`? Why would you do something you don't want to do? Blink twice if someone is forcing you.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like [fixed_capacity_vector](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0843r0.html) (or boost's [static_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html)? It's not clear exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Quentin Yea a wrapper class would probably do the trick and be little to no overhead if I'm not mistaken? I could just expose the functionality of std::vector we want to maintain and call it a day.  Much more simple than dealing with this C-style allocation (which you already pointed out is not complete in this example)!

Comment: @Nelfeal fixed_capacity_vector looks like a potential alternative but looks like you can delete Essentially I want a vector with very limited functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Quentin's comment above an example implementation of a wrapper class could be done with the following template class. This allows for run-time initialization benefits of std::vector while allowing/disallowing other operations as needed. Access to the objects it contains would be the same via the subscript operator.

```
template <class T>
class RuntimeArray{
    private:
    std::vector<T> values;
    public:
    RuntimeArray() = delete;
    RuntimeArray(const std::vector<int>& inputs){ // can be whatever type to initialize
        values.reserve(inputs.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++){
            values.emplace_back(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    T& operator [](int i){
        return values[i];   
    }
    const T& operator[](int i) const{
        return values[i];
    }
    // std::vector without std::vector::push_back or std::vector::erase etc.
};
```

Comment: Couple notes, the constructor should take `inputs` as const reference to avoid copy. `emplace_back` should take `inputs[i]` directly to create `T` in place. There should also be `const` version of `operator[]`.